# Javascript - Iterate the properties of an object and change them

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wish to iterate over an object's properties and change them all to include `""` around the value stored in them. 
This object is passed to a REST call and the above format must be enforced. I prefer to handle the addition of `""` in a central location, rather when assigning the actual values (the code is very complex and long).

I know that you can iterate through the object's properties easily:

```
$.each(queryOptions, function(obj){console.log(obj)})
```

However, can I somehow get reference to the actual property and set it from within the iteration?

Input:

```
queryOptions.value1 = 1234;
queryOptions.value2 = "testing";
queryOptions.value3 = 555;
```

Desired output:

```
queryOptions.value1 = "1234";
queryOptions.value2 = ""testing"";
queryOptions.value3 = "555";
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you completely sure that you really need to do that?  It seems pretty odd to me.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't actually have to serialize the object as JSON?  That would make some sense, but having to add quotes inside strings is weird.

Comment: @Pointy, this is a very specific and weird implementation caused by .NET even weirder handling of json with its .NET webservices support for json. They have improved their support with WCF and Web API which I intend to migrate to in the future.

Comment: `queryOptions.value2 = testing;` - What's that supposed to mean?

Comment: testing is a string, when you view the object's properties it will be surrounded by "" in the viewer. But, in order to demonstrate my point I removed the "".

Comment: @joola `queryOptions.value2 = testing;` isn't possible if you're taking about converting the name of the variable to a string. ...Unless the value of the variable is the name of the variable or... you're parsing the script as text.

Comment: I edited the question to be more true to reality with regards to the missing "".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree with Pointy that this seems an odd requirement. But if it's really a requirement:

Using [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

```
$.each(queryOptions, function(key) {
    queryOptions[key] = '"' + queryOptions[key] + '"';
});
```

Or just using JavaScript without any library stuff:

```
var key;
for (key in queryOptions) {
    if (queryOptions.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        queryOptions[key] = '"' + queryOptions[key] + '"';
    }
}
```

Comment: And the OP is happy with the answer :) sometimes the simplest approach just stares at you. Many thanks.

Comment: Removed my down vote. You only had jQuery up there which is totally unnecessary.

Comment: @iambriansreed: The OP specifically mentioned `each`, which is why I did that. A lot of people use `each`, liking the encapsulation of the iterator (which is why we have `forEach` and such on arrays in ES5 now).

Comment: Didn't know about `forEach` existed. need to brush up on my ES5.

Comment: @iambriansreed: If you've already included the library for something else, you may as well use it for this as well.

Comment: @Eric Because it is overkill and a stripped down native JavaScript like in my example is faster and is actually what the jQuery `.each` is doing anyways. Just because you have a sledge hammer doesn't mean you use it for finishing nails.

Comment: @iambriansreed: *"...a stripped down native JavaScript like in my example is faster..."* Not in any way a human can notice (http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2012/02/foreach-and-runtime-cost.html), and speed is not the only factor when writing code.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I totally missed that he actually wanted quotes around the value. Not just a conversion to string. WTH?

Comment: @iambriansreed: Yeah, I find it a really strange requirement as well. But he did reconfirm it, so... :-)